# C# Substring With Mobile Number

Tags: c#, validation, substring

C# I need the code to check that all the characters are digits in a mobile number and that the first character is +, it has to be done using substrings!

this is what I have:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string phoneNumber = "0";
        bool symbol;
       // int val = 11;
        while (phoneNumber.Length != 11)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please Enter Your Telephone Number, Make Sure It Starts Off in '+44'");
            phoneNumber = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        symbol = Check(phoneNumber);
    }
    public static bool Check(string phoneNumber)
    {
        if (phoneNumber[0] == '+')
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < phoneNumber.Length; i++)
            {
                if(!char.IsDigit(phoneNumber[i]))
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
                    return true;
            }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < phoneNumber.Length; i++)
            {
                if(!char.IsDigit(phoneNumber[i]))
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
                    return true;
            }
        }
         }

    }
```

Comment: why substrings? is that a homework task and that's a requirement? Else, a regular expression is the perfec tool for this. Also, you didn't asked nothing, if you have any trobule, specify it so we can help you.

Comment: The All extension will shorten your code to two lines

Comment: What country is the phone number?

Comment: UK number @JeffOrris

Comment: do we need to check for hyphen ('-') and white space (" ")?

Comment: @Steve I don't know how to use the All extension

Comment: Well, if this is a homework and you have no idea on how Substring works... better read the MSDN documentation about Substring, try something and when you have a problem, then ask for help. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @JeffOrris nope.. just if +44 are the first three characters, I didn't mention that sorry

Comment: replace everything in the Check with _int skipCount = (phoneNumber[0] == '+' ? 1 : 0);_ and then follow with _return phoneNumber.ToCharArray().Skip(skipCount).All(x => char.IsDigit(x));_ However this is not an answer to your question because it doesn't use substring

Comment: Substrings? Ew. This seems like a perfect job for regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Substring to make a string that is everything after the first character, then check to see if all characters in the substring are digits:

```
    private static bool Check(string phoneNumber)
    {
        return (phoneNumber[0] == '+' && phoneNumber.Substring(1).All(char.IsDigit));
    }
```

Comment: Well it is accepted now but I am not sure that this matches the code above. In the original code the OP accepts as valid also a string of all numbers without a leading +

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated